# Can't scroll page with mouse wheel while using html5 drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

It seems that it is not possible to scroll the page using the mouse wheel when using html5 drag and drop feature. I have seen this problem occuring in any html5 drag and drop live demo. any workaround to solve that issue?

Comment: Hi @Shelef, I got the same problem. I wonder if you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the only reason why this happens, but in my case there was an overlay element with `pointer-events: none` which prevented scrolling while dragging in Chrome

Answer (score -1):

There are some demo where page scrolling is possible. try this code:

```
  <style type = "text/css">
     #boxA, #boxB {
        float:left;padding:10px;margin:10px;-moz-user-select:none;
     }

     #boxA { background-color: #6633FF; width:75px; height:75px;  }
     #boxB { background-color: #FF6699; width:150px; height:150px; }
  </style>

  <script type = "text/javascript">

     function dragStart(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
        ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
        return true;
     }

     function dragEnter(ev) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return true;
     }

     function dragOver(ev) {
        return false;
     }

     function dragDrop(ev) {
        var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
        ev.stopPropagation();
        return false;
     }
  </script>
```

```
  <center>
     <h2>Drag and drop HTML5 demo</h2>
     <div>Try to move the purple box into the pink box.</div>

     <div id = "boxA" draggable = "true"
        ondragstart = "return dragStart(ev)">
        <p>Drag Me</p>
     </div>

     <div id = "boxB" ondragenter = "return dragEnter(ev)" 
        ondrop = "return dragDrop(ev)" 
        ondragover = "return dragOver(ev)">Dustbin
     </div>
  </center>
```

Resize the window.

Comment: is there any running example?

Answer (score -2):

This is working code. Attachment can be shown of the screenshot of the working page. I changed the source code by adding some div to make the page scroll. 
Code source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

</style>
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>

    <img id="drag1" src="images.jpg" alt="image can not be seen"draggable="true"       ondragstart="drag(event)" width="300" height="68">
<div id="middle" style="height:50px;width:1200px;background-color:blue;margin-top:300px;"><p>This is a test div</p> </div>
    <div id="bottom" style="height:50px;width:1200px;background-color:yellow;margin-  top:400px;"><p>This is another test div</p></div>


</body>
</html>
```